# Möbius cross energy in $S^3$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, knot-link

Let $\gamma_i$, $i=1,2$ be two loops in $\mathbb R^3$. The Möbius cross energy of the pair is defined by
$$
E(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)=\iint_{S^1\times S^1}\frac{|\gamma'_1(u)|\cdot|\gamma'_2(v)|}{|\gamma_1(u)-\gamma_2(v)|^2}du\,dv.
$$
If I want to work in the round $S^3$ intrinsically, is there any formula for the Möbius cross energy?

Comment: Isn't your formula for $E(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)$ exactly what you are looking for?  If not, why not?

Comment: Just a warning. There have been a great deal of research on Mobius energy, O'Hara energy, Menger curvature etc. so unless you know exactly what you want to do, starting original research in this field might be difficult.

Comment: @RyanBudney The `standard' Hopf link in the round $S^3$ is two great circles. Their distance is $\pi/2$ point-wisely. Therefore, if you use this intrinsic distance, the energy is not $2\pi^2$ (Which is the energy of the link in the Euclidean $R^3$). However, if you use the distance of $\mathbb R^4$ restricted on $S^3$, which is non-Riemannian, then you have $2\pi^2$.

Comment: I suspect you are using the word "distance" in a non-standard way.  Perhaps you need to clarify what "distance" means, each time you state it.  Moreover, what does "intrinsic" mean to you?  I suspect your question has a fairly tautological answer once you notice that $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|$ can be written in terms of the Hopf-Rinow metric on $S^3$.  This involves a little trigonometry.

Comment: @RyanBudney For "intrinsic distance" I mean the distance between two points can be realized by the length of a curve joining two points. Every complete Riemannian metric induces such a distance. But if you restrict the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb R^n$ on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, you will have a non-intrinsic distance on the sphere. BTW. I tried to google "Hopf-Rinow metric", but got nothing. Did I miss something trivial?

Comment: Not trivial, but I thought this material was standard in introductory differential geometry courses.  The main observation is that $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|$ is equal to $2 - 2\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the "intrinsic distance" or what is often known as the Hopf-Rinow metric distance between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.  This follows from the Hopf-Rinow theorem, knowledge of the geodesics in a sphere and the "law of cosines".

Comment: Typo, replace $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|$ above with $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|^2$.